# How to use a vector of unique pointers in a dll exported class with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

A simple example

```
class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
public:
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> v;
};
```

Error in VS2013 compilation for deleted copy constructor of `unique_ptr`. If I remove `__declspec(dllexport)`, it is fine. If I use only `unique_ptr<int> v`, it is fine too. Is this a compiler bug? Any way to work around it? Thanks.

You may try it on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ with the following complete code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
public:
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> v;
};

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
}
```

yielding the compiler error:

```
Compiled with /EHsc /nologo /W4 /c
main.cpp
main.cpp(9): warning C4251: 'A::v': class 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'A'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
c:\tools_root\cl\inc\xutility(2144): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
c:\tools_root\cl\inc\memory(1430): note: see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator ='
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
c:\tools_root\cl\inc\xutility(2165): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> *,
            _InIt=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> *
        ]
c:\tools_root\cl\inc\vector(973): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_impl<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _OutIt=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> *,
            _Ty=int,
            _InIt=std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> *
        ]
c:\tools_root\cl\inc\vector(956): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::operator =(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
main.cpp(10): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>::operator =(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
main.cpp(9): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
```

Comment: Clear problem description, compiler output, MCVE - if only all SO questions looked like this!

Comment: If I might suggest: Just don't do this.  What do you perceive as an advantage of putting this class in a DLL instead of just linking it?  The main advantages of DLLs (in particular, reusability) no longer apply when you export classes.

Comment: I agree with Ben. If you want to have the benefits of DLLs, you need to export only a C API (or, see the classic "hourglass interface" [presented at CppCon 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y)). Otherwise, just use static linking (.lib / .a files). Dealing with C++ ABI issues when distributing / reusing DLLs is such a nightmare that their advantages pale in comparison.

Comment: @BenVoigt It is better not to do it if dll advantages don't show here. Currently, I have a project which makes a dll kernel-computation library (most are classes) for a GUI to use. Is it better to use a static library for the kernel computation? Thanks.

Comment: @MikaelPersson Can you also give me some of your thoughts about my question on using static linrary for my kernel computation (most are classes)? Thanks. (please see my previous comments)

Comment: @user1899020: Yes, static linking will work very well for that and without any of the complications associated with DLLs.

Comment: @ben patching can be made a touch easier with DLLs if you have divided the code base up a bit.  Even if you cannot patch over ABI breaks (or standard library version changes).  Also, plugins are possible with DLLs and stable ABIs.  If you do drop down to the level of a C interface, you get these benefits *without* nearly as strong ABI requirements, but putting stuff in a DLL is easier than marshalling everything down to C.

Comment: @Yakk: Plugins and patching are what don't work, at least, not in any useful way.  Patching just portions of the product leads to ODR violations.  And wrt plugins, because neither the main application nor the plugins can move to a new compiler version without the other, and upgrading a dozen projects across multiple organization simultaneously is not feasible, everyone gets stuck on the original compiler version -- forever.  A very high price to pay.  Marshaling down to C global exports and COM interfaces is the only way to distribute a library as a binary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears adding `__declspec(dllexport)` forces the compiler to define the implicitly-declared copy constructor and copy assignment operator (normally, this only happens if they're used). These in turn call the copy constructor/assignment operator of `v`. But the copy operations of `std::vector<T>` are ill-formed for a non-copyable `T`, such as `std::unique_ptr`. Hence the error.

When the member is just `std::unique_ptr`, the problem does not occur, because that has copy operations explicitly deleted and so the default copy operations of `A` become deleted as well.

So the issue is solved if you explicitly delete the copy operations:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
public:
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> v;
};
```

Of course, if you *want* copy functionality, defining them yourself would help as well.

Comment: Not really "wrong", so to speak. `vector<unique_ptr<int>>`'s copy constructor is not deleted; it merely will fail to instantiate. As a result, `A`'s copy constructor isn't deleted either. Ditto for copy assignment.

Comment: @T.C. You're right of course. I will re-word the answer.

Comment: `A(A&&)=default; A& operator=(A&&)=default;` would give you move semantics (if your compiler wasn't broken, oh wait, nm) and would remove the need to `delete` the copy ctors.

Comment: Since the entire class is being exported, all member functions of the class, whether used or not, need to be instantiated and exported since they may be needed by code that imports the class.